# How to Pass an Integer Variable Into a Formula Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm currently trying to use an integer variable into a Sum formula using VBA. I've referenced [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337510/sum-formula-vba) as well as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37972695/how-to-pass-an-integer-variable-into-a-vba-formula) and implemented the subsequent recommendations but I'm still getting a Syntax error when I try to run the sub.

My code is the following:

```
Sub Sum_Column()
Dim fRow As Integer
fRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Cells(fRow + 1, 2).Formula = "=SUM(B2:B"fRow")"
End Sub
```

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Cells(fRow + 1, 2).Formula = "=SUM(B2:B" & fRow & ")"`

Comment: neither of the posted responses mentioned this ... in case you are a beginner ... do web search for "how to concatenate strings in VBA"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the part

```
"SUM(B2:B"fRow")"
```

It should be

```
"SUM(B2:B" & fRow & ")"
```